# Angular JS 1.X Access Resolved Promise Objects values

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, object, angular-promise

I have read a lot of posts on promises,resolving promises, and accessing the data however I cannot seem to. Following some posts on Stack Overflow has just caused errors, so I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong.

I have a function like so:

```
function getJsonl() {

  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    url: 'urlNotShownForSecurity',
    dataType:"json",
    method: 'GET',
    data:{"requestId":"123"},
    headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json","requestId":"123"},
  }).success(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
    console.log(data)

  }).error(function(error,status,headers,config) {
    deferred.reject(error);

  });

  return Promise.resolve(deferred.promise);
}
```

Here I return a json promise that has been resolved resulting in a json object I believe.

Printing to console I get the following:

[image]

Inside data is the information I need, it looks like this:

```
data:Array[8]
  0:Object
    description:"My description paragraph"
```

I have tried things with the returned object in my controller like:

```
vm.result = data.data[0].description;
vm.result = data[0].description
```

I have tried many different approaches in the view as well to access but I get 2 blank li tags and that is it.

I would like to be able to access the data so I populate a table. So if I can use it with ng repeat that would be great, as well as being able to access without because some data is used in more than just the table.

### Update

@DanKing, following your implementation I get the following output in console:
Now I am back with a promise object.

[image]

Comment: FYI, `success` and `error` methods are deprecated on recent `$http` implementations. Even if your angular still supports them, it would be better to code with an eye on the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though you're fundamentally misunderstanding the nature of promises.

$http() is an *asynchronous* function - that means it doesn't complete straight away, which is why it returns a promise.

It looks to me as though you're trying to call $http() and then get the result back and return it from your getJson1() method, *before* $http() has finished executing.

You can't do that. Your getJson1() method should just return the promise, so your calling method can chain onto it - like this:

```
getJson1().then(function(data) {
    // do some other stuff with the data
});
```

The whole point of promise chains is that they don't execute straightaway - instead you provide callback functions that will be executed at some indeterminate point in the future, when the previous operation completes.

Your getJson1() function just needs to do this:

```
return $http({
    url: 'urlNotShownForSecurity',
    dataType:"json",
    method: 'GET',
    data:{"requestId":"123"},
    headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json","requestId":"123"},
});
```

Comment: That explains why in console it has 2 undefined and than a promise object. Could you write an example using my json1? Your small version I am not fully sure how to implement with your last paragraph. Also wouldn't  promise.resolve fix it anyways?

Comment: OK, I've extended my answer. Promise.resolve() is an ES6 standard and AFAIK it isn't applicable to Angular promises. But even if it was it wouldn't help you here, and I'm a little unclear what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: I am testing that solution now. That is half of the question. The other half is how to access the values in the object. using a directive like ng-repeat for example

Comment: @L1ghtk3ira - I'm not sure you really understand Angular or promises. It sounds like you need someone to teach you the fundamentals, rather than just asking one or two random questions on Stack Overflow. Have you considered looking for a suitable training course? To try to answer your question though - in my example above, instead of "`// do some other stuff with the data`", just add the data as a property to your scope - then you will be able to access it from your html.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, rewrote the answer as a complete component to show the moving parts.

$http returns a promise so your original `getJsonl` call can be simplified. Using your original $http parameters this should dump your API response to the screen if you use the `<json-thing>` tag:

```
angular.module('yourModuleName')
.component('jsonThing', {
  template: '<pre>{{$ctrl.thing|json}}</pre>',
  controller: function ($http) {
    var $ctrl = this;
    getJsonl()
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response); // we have the $http result here
        $ctrl.thing = response.data; // allow the template access
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error); // api call failed
      });

    // call backend server and return a promise of incoming data
    function getJsonl() {
      return $http({
        url: 'urlNotShownForSecurity',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: { requestId: '123'},
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', requestId: '123'}
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Using the promise with resolve i have the data it is displayed in console log, however I cannot access it individually or as a whole in html

Comment: You don't need the extra complexity of an additional `defer` and `promise`.  But if you insist, then you should return the _promise_ in the `getJsonl` method and _not resolve it_!  The resolution takes place in your `success` method.

Comment: I am confused. Could you show an example? From what I read I need the resolve method

Comment: I rewrote my answer with an example using your original parameters.

Comment: I cannot just dump the screen I need to access each value for example like data[0].description. or something like ng-repeat

Answer (score -1):

```
getJsonl().then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
},function(err){
  console.log(err);
})
```

should work. Where is your $http request and where is your call to getJsonl() will also make a difference. So choose that carefully when implementation. If you are using this in a service then you will have to return the function result say

```
this.somefunction = function (){
     return getJonl();
}
```

and in your controller inject the service and do the following

```
service.somefunction().then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },function(err){
      console.log(err);
    })
```

Comment: It is in a factory that is binded to a controller that is binded to a html pages div element

Comment: My http request is in the getjson method

Comment: Alright so that brings me back to my object shown in console with the promise gone. So how do I access each value individually and or using something like ng-repeat? I am trying things like data[0].description for example and getting errors.THanks

Comment: Please update the question your data structure, referencing code, and the error details. Its your reference that breaking the code. Assign to scope and do ng-repeat if you are using data[0].description directly.